# git repo inside another without any connection between them

Tags: git

My HOME(~) directory is a git repo with only config files like vimrc and bashrc (I have used a .gitignore with "*", and I use add -f, so nothing else get added).

Now inside my HOME, I have more directories with code projects that are themselves git reops, and sometimes even more git repos inside thus.

**Basically, do this setup can cause problems?** 
Do the .git folder of inner repos will be added recursively ?

I heard about "git submodules" but if I don't need any connection between the repos - so do I need to read about it t all ?

**Thanks.**

Comment: Even if there's no problem, you could still avoid this by isolating your config files in a clean dedicated repo, and link them in your HOME.

Comment: I know about it. but why it's better? it's seems like just adding another dir to my system. Thanks.

Comment: You will have to use a subdirectory anyway when you will want to clone it to a new HOME, because you can't clone in a non-empty directory. You could then move everything back to ~, but then it's a matter of choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problems at all, just add those directories in the `.gitignore` of your HOME directory and you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work just fine only that the outer repository will notify that something is changed in inner repository and you would have to go to this inner and commit it there.
So it basically works for me like git modules out of the box.